# Magento2 how to batch update meta title on product pages

Tags: magento2

I have a multi-site site. When I add products in batches to the new site, I need to modify the meta title of the products on the new site. There are too many products, and I don't want to edit them one by one, which is too time-consuming

Comment: you can export product csv from your old site, and import it.

Comment: I want to operate by the scheduled task SQL statement, how to use

Comment: did you mean you need to run sql queries.

Comment: Yes i want use sql